# Trouble using dscl to create and add user to group

Tags: macos, permissions, zsh

I am working on a fix for a piece of software where the provider suggests we should create a user group with `dscl` and then grant the group ownership of a folder.

Users in our environment are on macOS 12+.

So far, I am using zsh to determine $LIVEUSER and running the following:

```
dscl . create /groups/appname

dscl . -append /groups/appname GroupMembership $LIVEUSER
```

This does not seem to be working as intended. The command returns with no errors, and when I run:

```
dscacheutil -q group -a name appname
```

The command finishes with no output. Running something like:

```
dscacheutil -q group -a name admin
```

Returns the name, password, gid, and users within the group.

How can I use `dscl` to create a group and add a user to that group successfully?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you give the new group a group ID number? Also, it shouldn't matter, but in principle you should also add the user's UUID/GeneratedUID to the group's `GroupMembers` list (not to be confused with `GroupMembership`, which holds short usernames). In general, I recommend using `dseditgroup` to create and manage groups, instead of editing the DS entries manually (for instance, see my answer to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13132/how-to-add-user-to-a-group-on-command-line)).